# replacing vs object browser with reflector?

Tags: visual-studio, reflector, objectbrowser

Has anyone tried to build or seen a plugin for visual studio that replaces the object browser of with Reflector? It would be really cool if I do "Go to Definition" I would end up in Reflector at the correct place instead of in the VS object browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [TestDriven.net](http://www.testdriven.net/) Visual Studio addin (also from [here](http://reflectoraddins.codeplex.com/)) adds a menu item to go to Reflector from within Visual Studio. I don't think it replaces "Go to Definition" though, so you would have to click the correct (ie. Reflector) menu item.

A [Reflector Pro](http://www.red-gate.com/messageboard/viewforum.php?f=109&topicdays=0&start=0) (paid for version of Reflector) is coming soon, which gets installed into Visual Studio, so it *may* have the ability to decompile source code using Reflector instead of using the object browser. If not, ask for it as a new feature on their forum :)

**EDIT:** as if almost on cue, the beta of Reflector Pro [was announced today](http://www.simple-talk.com/community/blogs/alex/archive/2010/01/20/87639.aspx) and it does have an "Open in Reflector" command.

Comment: The 'Open in Reflector' command is not limited to Reflector Pro, it's been added to the free version of the tool as well.